# how to post embend many using express js and mongose not only key but object can also insert i just input refrencess key

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, embed

i try to insert embed using expresss and mongose this my schema of roles

```
import mongoose, { mongo } from "mongoose";

const role = mongoose.Schema({
    'name':{
        type: String,
        require: true
    },
    'user':{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Users"
    },
    'applications':[{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Applications"
    }]
    },
    { timestamps: true },);
export default mongoose.model('Roles', role);
```

and sschema of applications

```
import mongoose, { mongo } from 'mongoose';

const application = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      require: true,
    },
    parent: {
      type: Number,
      require: false,
    },
    order: {
      type: Number,
      require: false,
    },
    appRoleId: [
      {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Roles',
      },
    ],
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);
export default mongoose.model('Applications', application);
```

when i try to save role like this

```
POST http://localhost:3000/role
Content-Type: application/json
{
    "name": "administrator testing",
    "applications": [
        "636341e4b8f0b311829f5cb8"
    ]

}
```

i just want put my applicationsid and then the object of applications will be input at all,not inputing manual like this

```
POST http://localhost:3000/role
Content-Type: application/json
{
    "name": "administrator testing",
    "applications": [
        appId: "636341e4b8f0b311829f5cb8"
        name: example
        etc
    ]
}
```

and this my controller

```
export const saveRole = async (req, res) => {
  const app = await Application.find();
  const role = new Role(req.body);
  // console.log(role);
  for (const roles of role) {
    const newRole = await Role.create({ ...roles });
    //add app to role
    foundApp.role.push(newRole._id);
    await foundApp.save();
  }
  // res.json(foundApp);
};
```

my expectation data in mongo compas like this
[image]

Comment: Can you please check your provided code of your controller? The code found there does not really make sense from my point of view (variable names are not correct, etc.). Can you also post as code formatted what your expected data is and what is currently not correct?

Comment: Well, why don't you simply use `const role = new Role.create(req.body);` then. This should be enough.

Comment: didnt use looping sir?my expectation like this sir:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/624Nk.png

Comment: You defined in your schema that you want to store a reference to an application document in your role schema. The structure you provided can therefore not be stored in this way in your role collection. If you want to achieve this structure, you should use nested documents, not referenced ones. Nevertheless to me it looks more like you only want to store the reference and build this structure when you query a role. In order to achieve this you would need to `populate` the applications in your query.

Comment: @verybeginnercode You basically need to store the whole application document in the `applications` property of the `Roles` schema, correct?

Comment: wht kind of typical schema of nested?if references the schemaa like this type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, if nested?

Comment: @Ipizzinidev yup sir yup,but just insert the key referencess and i want automaticly the data object applications will be insert.there is can or not?

Comment: @Ipizzinidev yup sir yes yes,the data application is already input by me sir,